# How to replace a character in a specific position in a flat file

Tags: shell

I am having a flat file with huge data, there are 924 characters in one line, in solaris server. Now i want to goto the specific position in each line - say 234, and check if it has "R" as the character, if it has "R" then replace it with "x". How can i write a shell script with these conditions?

Comment: `there are 924 characters in one line` - you mean *each line*?

Comment: yes there are 924 characters in each line

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a Solaris system to test on: this should work:

```sh
sed -E 's/^(.{233})R/\1x/' file
```

That does not modify the file. To save a backup copy and modify the file in-place:

```sh
sed -i .bak -E '...' file
```

Use `-i ''` if you don't want a backup.

Reiterating: I don't have Solaris, and these option may not work with the Solaris sed.